# Как получить значение элемента html с помощью js?

Tags: javascript, html

Например:

```
<p id = "percent3" class = "percent3">0%</p>
```

Нужно получить значение процентов, то-есть 0%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('percent3').textContent;
```

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня не выводится.

Comment: А нет, єто я не тот єлемент взял. Спасибо за ответ!